# Is Programming Witchcraft or Actual Magic?

Tags: programming-languages

I may sound stupid, but few people say that programming is witchcraft (maybe Joking) as a Christian I Must take it seriously, because I am planning to become Software Architect in the future. Honestly I do not think it is like Witchcraft, since it has nothing to do with evil spiritual world. How can compiler translate Code into machine code... Please take seriously and answer ASAP. Thank you !

Comment: As a programmer, I sacrifice a virgin every month to improve my efficiency. Dunno if the blood pentacle I draw is considered witchcraft though.

Comment: @Nathaniel I wouldn't do that if I were you, I heard virgin sacrifices have a negative impact on space complexity.

Comment: @ThePirate42 but what about time complexity? I heard it can improve it up to an exponential factor

Comment: @nirshahar Really? I guess I could try some virgin-puppy hybrid approach then. I'll do some benchmarks and I'll let you know.

Comment: Planning is replacing happenstance with misconception.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, programming is magic: you get into a small dark room and smash keyboards and poof you got infinite money.

Just kidding! programming isn't magic at all, nor witchcraft. If you will learn computer science or electronics, you will know how computers actually work. There is a lot of complex physics going on behind the scenes, that allows computers to actually compute. Programmers just know what kinds of things the computer can compute, and they know how to specify it in the computer so it will do what they want: this is called programming.

Higher level programs will all get compiled into something called "machine code", which basically is just all operations a computer knows how to calculate. Of course, this "compilation" process is also some program people wrote, that is also running in "machine code". In fact, the very first compiler just *had* to be written in machine code, because there was nothing to compile it to machine code otherwise. Then, all other programs and compilers will build upon previous ones, until we reach what we have today.